# Python Selenium select dynamic xpath with variable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, bdd

I am trying to locate a visible element that will change based on what the user enters on the website. I am successful if use the follow with a static XPath search string:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Hierarchy']/following::input[@id='label-input']")))
```

Default-Test will change arbitrarily and I have how to get this value, but I have not been successful using a variable in the XPath search:Test method 1 Does not work

```
dtg_found = "Default-Test"
```

Test method 2 does not work, this is the actual method for locating the value

```
dtg_opt_1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='" + label_name + "']/following::input[@id='label-input']")))
```

Facing below error:

Answer (score 0):

Try using the f-Strings like below:

```
dtg_opt_1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[text()={label_name}]/following::input[@id='label-input']")))
```

Comment: It didn't work for me :(
I am expecting as below function .

    def enter_the_value_in_textbox(self, label_name, label_value):
        # self.input_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[text()={label_name}]/following::input[@id='label-input']", label_value)
        ele = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[text()={label_name}]/following::input[@id='label-input']")
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ele)